# Python deleting half the elements in a list after iterating through it

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I've been completely stumped on this one:

I have the following python code:

```
def remove(self, widgets):
    for widget in widgets:
        widget_found = False
        for widget_sig in self.widgets:
            if widget_sig.id == widget:
                #remove all objects from selected widget
                widget_found = True
                to_remove = widget_sig.objs
                for obj in to_remove:
                    #objs are all intances of oo_canvas classes
                    obj.destroy()
                    self._build(widget, obj)
        if not widget_found:
            #if we iterated through the entire list and still couldn't find anything
            raise mockingbird_errs.InternalMockingbirdError("The requested widget was not registered with this builder: "+str(widget))
```

This should be pretty straight forward. The thing is, it never iterates through to_remove correctly. For some reason, it skips every other element. Even more baffling, is if I have it print the length of to_remove before and after the for loop, it prints 254 and 127. Huh? As far as I know, iterating through a list does not involve deleting every other element.

Am I missing something straightforward? What on earth is going on?

Comment: what is obj.destroy() doing???

Comment: obj.destroy() changes one attribute in the class from False to True. Later, a different method will be called on obj that actually collects the data and uses it.

Comment: There is actually no code inside your snippet actually performing a remove operation. You are hiding details from us!

Comment: If you actually want to delete half the `list` (as opposed to just one element), you're usually better off building a new `list` of just the elements you want to keep. This doesn't work in all cases (e.g., if someone else is holding a reference to the same `list`, and needs to see the changes), but when it does, it's easier to reason about, and usually simpler code, and more efficient.

Comment: I'll just clarify quickly. I wasn't trying to delete half the list. I was trying to iterate through the whole list without deleting any of it. Anyway, I fixed the problem by copying the list first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ... it skips every other element.

That's because you keep deleting them, shortening the list by 1. And then you move on to the next index. Either work backwards, or iterate over a copy of the list.

Comment: I did try iterating over the copy, and that fixed the problem. Thanks.

Comment: How to do that ?